# How to take input from user to select and reference Dictionary Key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key, user-input

Writing a food ordering program for school, and am running into the issue of TypeError when trying to take the user input to select the menu item, then use that input to refer quantity value to that dictionary.

`

```
menu = {
1: {"item": "Green Beret Omelette", "price": "$12.99"},
2: {"item": "Get to the Chopped Salad", "price": "$14.99"},
3: {"item": "Pump You Up Protein Shake", "price": "$9.99"},
4: {"item": "I'll Be Baby Back Ribs", "price": "$22.99"},
5: {"item": "Let Off Some Steamed Vegetables", "price": "$4.99"},
6: {"item": "The Ice Cream Cometh", "price": "$15.99"}
}


key = int(input("Please select your item:\n"))
    if int(key) < 1 or int(key) > 6:
        print("Invalid selection. Please try again. \n")
        isOrdering = True
        continue

quan = int(input("Enter quantity: \n")), menu.update[key]({"quantity": quan})
```

The error I'm currently running into is "Exception has occurred: TypeError 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable" for the line:

quan = int(input("Enter quantity: \n")), menu.update[key]({"quantity": quan})

I tried the code above based on a previous attempt at asking that a friend posted for me. Threw the same error as I had in my initial attempt at solving.

The expected/intended output/update (whatever you want to call it) is:

menu choice: 1

quantity: 3

dictionary update: 1: {"item": "Green Beret Omelette", "price": "$12.99", "quantity": 3}

Comment: In first step split the last line into two lines: get the user input first. Than figure out how to add a new (key,value) to the VALUE of the `menu` dictionary for the `key`. What you want to update is menu[key] ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
menu = {
1: {"item": "Green Beret Omelette", "price": "$12.99"},
2: {"item": "Get to the Chopped Salad", "price": "$14.99"},
3: {"item": "Pump You Up Protein Shake", "price": "$9.99"},
4: {"item": "I'll Be Baby Back Ribs", "price": "$22.99"},
5: {"item": "Let Off Some Steamed Vegetables", "price": "$4.99"},
6: {"item": "The Ice Cream Cometh", "price": "$15.99"}
}
from pprint import pprint
print("       CHOOSE AN ITEM FROM THE MENU:")
pprint(menu)
print()

key = 0
while int(key) < 1 or int(key) > 6:
    key = int(input("Please select your item (1 or 2 up to 6):\n"))
    if int(key) < 1 or int(key) > 6:
        print("Invalid selection. Please try again. \n")

quan = int(input("Enter quantity: \n"))
menu[key]["quantity"] = quan

pprint(menu)
print()
print(f'You ordered {key}: {menu[key]["item"]}, quantity: {quan},  total price=${quan*float(menu[key]["price"][1:])}')
```

Comment: This didn't work. It just created an infinite loop asking for input

Comment: Not guessing, just missed a tab :p

I'm quite terrible at programming.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are attempting to do is concatenate to your menu dictionary before it even knows what 'quan' is.

trying getting and then resetting it.

```
menu = {
    1: {"item": "Green Beret Omelette", "price": "$12.99"},
    2: {"item": "Get to the Chopped Salad", "price": "$14.99"},
    3: {"item": "Pump You Up Protein Shake", "price": "$9.99"},
    4: {"item": "I'll Be Baby Back Ribs", "price": "$22.99"},
    5: {"item": "Let Off Some Steamed Vegetables", "price": "$4.99"},
    6: {"item": "The Ice Cream Cometh", "price": "$15.99"}
}


key = int(input("Please select your item:\n"))

if (int(key) < 1 or int(key) > 6):
    print("Invalid selection. Please try again. \n")
    isOrdering = True
    


m1 = menu[key]

quan = int(input("Enter quantity: \n"))

q = {"quantity":quan}

m1.update(q)

menu.update({key: m1})

print("dictionary updated:",list(menu.keys())[0],":",menu[key])
```

============================

Please select your item:

1

Enter quantity:

3

dictionary updated: 1 : {'item': 'Green Beret Omelette', 'price': '$12.99', 'quantity': 3}